# CDN and URL's with query-strings

Tags: url, cdn

We have an images folder on our web servers that we may publish via a CDN. Sometimes we append query-string like syntax to URL's to help us freshen content that has changed, even though it rarely does. Example:

```
/images/file.png?20090821
```

will URL's like this work with your average content-delivery-network?

Comment: Is this query string standardized? Or is that a parameter that you would need to define yourself in your REST API for the CDN somehow to actually fetch the file from that date?

Comment: Hi @Josh! No standardization here - just home-grown and very easy to change if a CDN requires it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, We use Akamai, which keeps a cached copy of each distict url requested including the querystring.  So the first request for /images/file.png?20090821 will go to the origin server.  Requests there after for /images/file.png?20090821 will get the image from the Akamai servers.  The next day, assuming the img src changes to /images/file.png?20090822, the first request will go to the origin server again.

Comment: But, a better way is to instead add the hash/md5 to the file name itself (/images/file-299388299389299asbsa88.png). That way caches which ignore query params will also detect and serve modified resources.

Answer (score 4):

Amazon CloudFront [turned on this feature in May 2012](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2012/05/amazon-cloudfront-support-for-dynamic-content.html)

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't have problem with CDN. However, you may have problem with browsers. Some browsers wouldn't cache any content with query string. Even though it may be faster to fetch the image from CDN but it will not be as fast as cached image. So you want do something like this,

```
/images/file.png/20090821
```

Our CDN provider also recommends a hash mechanism. When we publish our content, it adds a hash to the URL so you don't have to add the version yourself. Unfortunately, I don't know the details on how that magic is done.

Answer (score 0):

amazon cloudfront won't propagate the query string.