# CDN vs web servers. Fundamental differences

Tags: rest, web-services, http, cdn

My understanding is that a CDN is effectively comprised of **HTTP** servers that are closer to the client. Their primary goal is to deliver cached **content** (e.g. multimedia) at **low latency**.  Is that understanding correct? Or is that analogy misguided?

If so, is it safe to state that CDNs would *typically*:

- not accept PUT / POST / DELETE requests that intend to *modify* data?
- not establish connections to a DB across the network to deliver or manipulate data in general

Or am I  wrong on the above and on how they are intended to be used in practice?

Comment: you put static files on CDN

Answer (score 9, accepted):

CDN is used to keep static files, for example HTML, JavaScript, CSS, images:

> A content delivery network is a geographically distributed group of
> servers optimized to deliver static content to end users. This static
> content can be almost any sort of data, but CDNs are most commonly
> used to deliver web pages and their related files, streaming video and
> audio, and large software packages.

See also [Using a CDN to Speed Up Static Content Delivery](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/using-a-cdn-to-speed-up-static-content-delivery)

So of course it can't contain API, access to DB or any server side logic.

Comment: Thanks, but when you say _"it can't contain API"_, it must accept `HTTP` requests, at least `GET`, no?

Comment: when you use url to request file from CDN, you send get request. About query string, it depends: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1330011/cdn-and-urls-with-query-strings